# Iterate through a list of lists of 2 values, saving them to variables

Tags: python, list

I have a list like:

```py
d = [('red', 1), ('blue', 2), ('green', 3))]
```

I would like to iterate through this list, getting each pairing of word and number and putting them into variables.

```py
for i, value in enumerate(d): 
    word = d[i(0)]
    value = d[i(1)]
    return word
    return value
```

This gives me TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: What did you expect from `i(0)`?

Comment: You probably meant `d[i][0]` but why not just `value[0]`? Or better yet: `for word, value in d`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe The original array was square brackets then circular ones, so I thought doing (0) would give me the first value aka the word for each i aka each pair in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way. Just unpack like this,

```
d = [('red', 1), ('blue', 2), ('green', 3)]
for color, num in d:
   print("Color:", color, "Number:", num)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code:

1. You don't have to enumerate the array, you can access value directly.
2. You have 2 returns. The second one will be skipped.
3. It is good to use functions if you want to return something
4. `d[i(0)]` and `d[i(1)]` doesn't make sense

Something like this could work for you:

```
d = [('red', 1), ('blue', 2), ('green', 3)]

for value in d: 
    word = value[0]
    value = value[1]
    print(word, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a Dictionary

```
var_map = dict(d)
```

Which would give,

```
{'red': 1, 'blue': 2, 'green': 3}
```

Then, access by using the key.

```
var_map['red']    # Gives 1
```

Comment: `dict` is just a better data structure for storing and accessing the data. Ultimately the OP want's to access the data. Maybe he/she can avoid that iteration. @Tomerikoo